# MongoDB Capped Collection Maximum allowable size

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I'm using a mongodb capped collection which is tailable. I want to set the size of it to a maximum value as I don't want to really have the oldest records removed according to the FIFO rule.

I want the data to pesist for as long as possible whilst keeping the features of a capped collection.

Thanks

Comment: If you don't want the oldest docs removed when the maximum size is reached, which ones do you want removed instead?

Comment: Ideally none removed.....I'll be inserting into the DB for only a certain period of time. So thats why I want to know the max size to ensure no documents are removed.

Comment: As long as you understand that the only way to remove anything from a capped collection, if it doesn't hit a TTL timeout or a size cap, is to delete the entire collection with `emptycapped`. You cannot delete individual documents.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can make the capped collection as big as you want; just set the `size` parameter of [`create_collection`](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/database.html#pymongo.database.Database.create_collection) to a value big enough to not run out of space.

Like this:

```
 db.create_collection('captest', capped=True, size=20000000000)
```

Comment: You could also create a capped collection like this to:   db.createCollection("mycoll", {capped:true, size:100000})

Answer (score 1):

You can create the capped collection using size (in bytes), or max (maximum number of documents to keep), or both in this case:

pymongo ->

```
self.db.create_collection('system_health_log', capped=True, size=5242880, max=5000)
```

mongo shell ->

```
db.createCollection("system_health_log", { capped : true, size : 5242880, max : 5000 } )
```

See more [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/) on Capped Collections.

Comment: It seems like the max property is not affecting the collection. I'm using server verion 3.2. After stats() on collection, the max stays NumberLong("6223372036...")

Comment: If you have an existing collection, I believe you have to convert it to capped. See more here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/capped-collections/